# datetime not converting from mysql to json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to generate google chart graph, just discovered while debugging (see live debug : [/googleChart.php](https://san.gotdns.ch/arduino/googleChart.php) ) that date is not getting converted;

```
// assumes dates are patterned 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $res['timestamp'], $match);
$year = (int) $match[1];
$month = (int) $match[2] - 1; // convert to zero-index to match javascript's dates
    $day = (int) $match[3];
$hours = (int) $match[4];
$minutes = (int) $match[5];
$seconds = (int) $match[6];
array_push($data['rows'], array('c' => array(
   array('v' => 'Date(' . date('Y,n,d,H,i,s', strtotime($res['timestamp'])).')'),
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Your live demo link ends on a page with invalid (or rather self-signed) certificate. Why does your code declare `$year`, `$month` etc. when you don't use them anywhere?

Comment: That's ok please open , I have self signed Wordpress on same URL

Comment: That's not ok, not when you have something like Let's Encrypt which gives you a properly signed HTTPS certificate for free. So either fix the cert issue on your live demo page or provide detailed description of what happens with your script (what is the input, what is the output, what the output should look like).

Comment: well, I would have to edit so many things to fix that , I have HTTP to HTTPS redirection on Apache2 configuration. if you can't help thats ok.

Comment: I think the downvote is appropriate, as you have so far failed to provide any answers regarding your code, such as how the problem manifests itself, what do you expect your code to do, what are the inputs etc.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz, you should provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

> what am i doing wrong ?

You are trying to parse the time string with a regular expression, and it is not the appropriate way to do this.

PHP doesn't accept zero-based months, so the following line is likely incorrect (I don't know what you have tried to do, as the variable is not used in the code):

```
$month = (int) $match[2] - 1; // convert to zero-index to match javascript's dates
```

However, the values parsed with regular expression are unused, as you are passing the original time string to `strtotime`:

```
date('Y,n,d,H,i,s', strtotime($res['timestamp']))
```

The expression above is correct as long as `$res['timestamp']` contains a valid input for `strtotime`, e.g.:

```
echo date('Y,n,d,H,i,s', strtotime('2016-12-18 16:04:10'));
//2016,12,18,16,04,10
```

---

Use `DateTime` class instead:

```
$time = '2016-12-18 16:04:10';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
echo $date->format('c');
//2016-12-18T16:04:10+00:00
```

Adjust the format string(s) according to your needs.